# is there a way to change the default template website in React.js (vite)

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, vite

every time I initialize a react js project the [default template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyoIa.png) contains a bunch of trash code that I have to remove by navigating to various files manually, I have been looking to make a template that is already blank so I can go straight to building from there, I can't seem to figure out how do I change the default template site, I guess that it is coming from a repo somewhere, there has to be a way to change the repo URL to change the template site.

Comment: https://github.com/vitejs/awesome-vite#react

Answer (score 0):

You can use [degit](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/degit) to start a new project from your own or a community template. If you have your base-project on GitHub, it's as easy as running

```
degit github:user/repo
```

Here's an example repo to get you started: https://github.com/akx/vite-react-ts-template